# Force number to 2 decimals (JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working with JavaScript: I'm using an API that returns monetary values as integers, such that $3.20 would be sent as 320.

I can convert easily by multiplying by 0.01, but this does not ensure 2 decimal places (I get 3.2, not 3.20).

I'm aware that `.toFixed(2)` is an easy way to do this, but `toFixed` returns a `String`, and Angular requires that the `ng-model` on a `<input type="number">` is a number and not a string. Any ideas?

Comment: You can only format number values in ECMAScript as type string, you can't format them as type number (there is no concept of integer, float or precision). You should add an AnguarJS tag to the question.

Comment: Will the numbers `3.20` and `3.2` cause different results? That is, given `320` and multiplying by `0.01` will result in `3.2`, given `321` and multiplying by `0.01` will result in `3.21`. Any calculations with these values should be fine. For displaying values you can use Angular's [currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) filter to format the numbers to 2 decimals.

Comment: To follow Brett's comment, the only time 3.2 and 3.20 are different is when they're strings.  When they're numbers, there is no possible difference.  If you need to see the extra 0 at some point, then you're back to talking about strings.